# Software Updater "404 Not Found" Error for Freshlight PPA

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. When I run the Software Updater, it checks for updates and finally gives the error `Failed to download repository information, check your internet connection`. However, if I click the "Settings" button in the lower left corner, and close the new GUI that opens up, then the software updater displays the list of updatable software if any, as it is expected to do usually. This has been happening for the past few months.

Running `sudo apt update` instead seems to give the following error:

```
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu xenial Release     
      404  Not Found

    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
    Reading package lists... Done                                      
    E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

While I am not prevented from actually installing updates this is a minor inconvenience and I am wondering what could be the root cause of it.

Comment: The error message is entirely correct: The PPA you added has nothing for Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial). It's as simple as removing that software source.

Comment: See this post about removing incorrect/outdated sources:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists