# Error message when typing command line $ sudo apt-get update

Tags: command-line, upgrade, 18.04, updates

i get an error when updating apt using $ sudo apt-get update
error is (Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80])
how can i solve it ??

Comment: i can't find your `Release` file, try use `main` on your ppa.

Comment: Duplicate of [Software Updater “404 Not Found” Error for Freshlight PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887383/software-updater-404-not-found-error-for-freshlight-ppa) - the PPA hasn't been active since 2015, you will need to remove it from your sources

Comment: use main???? how can i do it, i did't understand

Comment: @MuhamadNady please can you read https://askubuntu.com/a/92897/125220? In short, you need to open the Software & Updates program, click the Other Software tab, then untick the boxes for `http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu bionic Release`

Comment: @MuhamadNady with edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change with `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu bionic main ` saved and run update/upgrade again. i think steeldriver is right, see this https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/ubuntu/freshlight/+index# i cannot find your ppa for bionic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)